# Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000000 Error

Tags: iphone, debugging, macos, crash

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000000
```

What is Kernel protection error?
Where can i find the details about Exception type and code clearly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the full list of Mach kernel exceptions in /usr/include/mach/exception_types.h. Most if not all boil down to some flavor of “your program did something wrong”.

As hotpaw2 already told you, the specific thing you did wrong in this case was dereference `NULL`. You might have done this directly, in your own code, or indirectly by passing `NULL` to some library function or framework method. For example, passing `NULL` as one of the pointer arguments to `memcpy` is a good way to cause this crash.

Note that sending an Objective-C message to `nil` is OK—it does nothing and returns 0. On the other hand, passing `nil` as an argument in a message may not be OK. Passing `nil` where it isn't wanted may result in an NSException being thrown (which will cause a `SIGTRAP`, not `SIGBUS`, signal), or it may lead to some code eventually dereferencing `NULL`. Or it may be perfectly harmless. But you shouldn't do it unless the documentation explicitly says it's OK, because otherwise, even if it works now, it may break later.

Answer (score 3):

The OS doesn't allow a user app to access (read or write) certain memory addresses.  The address 0 (what a NULL or nil pointer points to) is one of those addresses.  A very common cause of this is code using a pointer that's never been initialized.