# "error:NULL" or "error:nil"?

Tags: objective-c, null

Just trying to figure out what's the best practice: when using method that takes `(NSError**)`, is it better to send it `nil` or `NULL`?

For example,

`NSArray *items = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:NULL];`

In the documentation it says "You may specify nil for this parameter if you do not want the error information." On the other hand, since its a double pointer, NULL seems to make sense as well?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Technically, `NULL` is the right answer and the docs are wrong.

In practice, it matters not.  `NULL` and `nil` are the same, for all intents and purposes.

While that could change and remain language compliant, it couldn't change without breaking tons and tons of stuff.

Feel free to file a bug, though.

Comment: They differ in their types. They're all zero, but "NULL" is a void *, "nil" is an id, and "Nil" is a Class pointer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564410/when-to-use-nil-and-null-in-objective-c

Comment: Yup;  thanks for the link.  And this is why, in this case, it should be NULL, because nil/Nil neither represent pointers to pointers to types;  it'd end up being something like (void*id*) or some such cast nonsense.

Comment: Thanks guys. What I'm worried is that if `NULL` somehow got dereferenced in the method, wouldn't it cause problems? According to this post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581544/exception-codes-kern-protection-failure-at-0x00000000-error], `nil` seems to be a safer choice?

Comment: `nil` or `NULL` matters not;  if you de-reference either, you'll crash.   Since it is a `(NSError**)`, it'd actually be something like `(NSError*void*)` and, thus, `NULL` is really the right choice.  But, again, it does't much matter in practice.